# angularjs ng-repeat binding bug

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Could anyone explain why in this http://codepen.io/mikeward/pen/gwcjt case focus lost anytime when char is typed, but in this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcrdh case everything works fine  ?

Comment: Please find the answer from this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829175/input-gets-unfocused/21829795#21829795)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the second example uses an object instead of an integer to bind the model to the view.

The model is binded to the scope of `ng-repeat` by reference and when the reference changes, the ng-repeat rerenders that model - so deletes the old element and creates a new.

Integers are stored by value, so basically when you change an integer, it becomes a completely new model (as a place in memory). But when you are using objects, the reference to that object remains the same when you change only the value of some of its properties.

So as a simple explanation, the element loses focus in the first example, because it's not the same element anymore.